# Risk analysis Information Security Checklist

Tags: risk-analysis

I wouldn't bother asking this question if it was easy to find.
In the past I've used a risk-analysis-checklist which was split up in serveral factors.

For example, there are **Human** factors, **Hardware** is one, **Organization** is one of them and **Environment** too.

I've lost this list and I wonder if anyone here could share this checklist with me. I've found [a partial list in Dutch](http://www.zbc.nu/security/aanpak-informatiebeveiliging-iso-27001-en-iso-27002/checklist-risico-analyse-informatiebeveiliging-iso-27001-en-nen-7510/) which helped me out for the factors except **Organization** and **Environment**.

If you have a question about my question(?), please add a comment and I will try to make it more clear.

Comment: Is the purpose of the checklist to quantitatively evaluate security risk? Or is it just supposed to remind you of what to look at?

Comment: @KnightOfNi Pointing me in the right direction for Organization and Environment would be a start. The complete list would be even more great.

Comment: Doesn't this depend a lot on what approach you're taking? Which framework are you using? ISO? COSO? ITIL? Was it a SANS publication?

Comment: The checklist I've had was based on either ISO or ITIL. But I'm just looking for the most basic checklist with examples of the most common risks. It does not have to be the exact list, pointing in the right direction with practical examples would be great. If you have any of them, please add them as answer even as they don't meet my request. They could gelp me alot!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you're looking for is [ISO/IEC 27002](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27002) - *Information technology – Security techniques – Code of practice for information security management*

> Outline for ISO27002:2005
>
> 1. Framework
> 2. Acceptable Use of Information Technology Resources
> 3. Information Security Definition & Terms
> 4. Risk assessment
> 5. Security policy – management direction
> 6. **Organization** of information security – governance of information security
> 7. Asset management – inventory and classification of information assets
> 8. **Human resources** security – security aspects for employees joining, moving and leaving an organization
> 9. **Physical and environmental security** – protection of the computer facilities
> 10. Communications and operations management – management of technical security controls in systems and networks
> 11. Access control – restriction of access rights to networks, systems, applications, functions and data
> 12. Information systems acquisition, development and maintenance – building security into applications
> 13. Information security incident management – anticipating and responding appropriately to information security breaches
> 14. Business continuity management – protecting, maintaining and recovering business-critical processes and systems
> 15. Compliance – ensuring conformance with information security policies, standards, laws and regulations